# Open-source software to monitor internet speed for long time

Tags: windows, open-source, internet

I am looking for a software which is having an ability to monitor internet speed/bandwidth for long duration,

The software should be capable of giving,

1. Internet speed graph
2. Should run long time
3. Compatible with Windows

Comment: Are you looking to track the available bandwidth (as provided by your ISP), or are you looking to track the used bandwidth by your devices? Please be aware that tracking the available bandwidth is usually only possible while no other devices use the network.

Comment: the web interface for the config software for your DSL router / cable modem might have such a feature already. Or do you want this for a single computer, e.g.your laptop only?

Comment: I am using internet at office and facing some issues with irregular network. I already briefed my internet is slow so I just want to report to network admin about this issue with some legit supporting info.

Comment: @GokulAnand to be honest I don't think your admin would love the idea of someone constantly doing speed checks. Maybe testing manually whenever problems arise would be a better option. The problem might also be with your system, looking for any programs that use a lot of bandwidth might be wise (especially on windows). Before doing constant checks I would definitely ask the admin if it is fine to do in their network. You could also ask the admin if he would like you to do any checks and how to do them.

Comment: Admin checks the network from server room and says everything is fine. But the switches, modem and everyconnection my room is old and outdated. So if I can give a graphical chart of all the ups and down it is easy for him to intrepret.

Comment: So there is no solution for my case?